# Pgsql find similar records in database

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sql-update, subquery

I have a table that has the layout of this

| sensor_id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-22 09:00:00 | 20.5 |
| 1 | 2020-12-22 10:00:00 | 21.5 |
| 1 | 2020-12-22 11:00:00 | 22.5 |
| 1 | 2020-12-22 12:00:00 | 23.5 |
| 2 | 2020-12-22 09:00:00 | 30.5 |
| 2 | 2020-12-24 10:00:00 | 31.5 |
| 2 | 2020-12-24 11:00:00 | 32.5 |
| 2 | 2020-12-24 12:00:00 | 33.5 |

I want to be able to do is find all references where sensor_id 1 and 2 have the same date.

What the plan is is to have a user select a station, which contains a list of sensors, to move data from station a to station b.  If there is any data on station a that already exists for this time on station b, then i don't need to move it.
I plan on 'moving' the data by running a simple `update readings set sensor_id = #a where sensor_id = #b`.

Note, the actual data I have billions of records, and I will be 'moving' data from one sensor_id to another, and often there will be a list of about 10 sensors to move at one time.

I don't really know where to start on this.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find all references where sensor_id 1 and 2 have the same date

For this you can use aggregation:

```
select time
from readings
when sensor_id in (1, 2)
group by time
having count(*) = 2
```

This gives you all `time`s for which both sensors have data.

From the rest of the question, I think that you want to change the sensor id (say, from `1` to `2`) on records when it will not conflict with an existing record. This suggests:

```
update readings r
set sensor_id = 2
where sensor_id = 1 and not exists (
    select 1 from readings r1 where r1.sensor_id = 2 and r1.time = r.time
)
```